# Storing CheckedItemPosition in the OnClick() of a SingleChoice alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to store and use the selected item of a single choice alert dialog.

This is my code so far:

```
            final String[] deviceNames = getBTPairedDeviceNames();
        int selpos;

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(deviceNames, 0, null)
        .setPositiveButton("O.K.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                // Do something useful with the position of the selected radio button

                selpos = selectedPosition;
            }
        })
        .show();

          Toast.makeText(this, "" + selpos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
```

I get a compile error when trying assign to selpos.  The error reads:

"Cannot refer to a non-final variable selpos inside an inner class defined in a different method"

setting selpos to final results in the error:

"The final local variable selpos cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"

How can I get the selected item's position out of the code block?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, declaring the variable as a field in your class (not in your function).

```
int selpos; //declare in class scope

public void yourFunction() {

//don't declare here
//int selpos;

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setSingleChoiceItems(deviceNames, 0, null)
    .setPositiveButton("O.K.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
            // Do something useful with the position of the selected radio button

            selpos = selectedPosition;
        }
    })
    .show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this does it. I'm sure I tried that, but can't have. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Just what it says. So change it to

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setSingleChoiceItems(deviceNames, 0, null)
    .setPositiveButton("O.K.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
            // Do something useful with the position of the selected radio button

            final int selpos = selectedPosition;
```

Make the variable `final` and move it inside the `onClick()`. Then depending on what you need to do with it you can send it to another function to be used

Comment: Thanks, codeMagic - your suggestion may work, but still leaves the issue of limited scope for selpos.  I haven't tried it as I have a working solution, but thanks for posting. Regards, Mike

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you got it working. The better way probably is better but its hard to say without knowing how/where else you are using it. If you only need it in one other spot, say a method to save, then passing it from `onClick()` to a specific function would make more sense as it would stick to the scope it needed

Comment: That's true.  In fact I've used that technique elsewhere now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable `selpos` as the main class(that extends activity) field so that you can access that variable from anywhere inside that class.

Example:

```
class ABC extends Activity
{
...
int selpos;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Shree. I think yours is the same answer as Kaya, but it wasn't so clear to me. Regards, Mike

Comment: @MichaelVincent No problem. And sorry for not making the answer more understandable.